# I am trying to insert the form content but it is printing null on console

Tags: javascript, ajax

*console.log(data) statement is printing null on console.I have to send the form data(whose id is "myform") to Java backend post method.But this code is not working properly.Could someone please tell the error?*

```
var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
        var data = new FormData();
        console.log(data);
         jQuery.ajax({
             url: '/WeatherApi/UserDetailsController',
             data: data,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             method:'POST',
             success: function(data){
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
```

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) - you need to pass the form

Answer (score 1):

```
      var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
    var data = new FormData(myform);
    console.log(...data);
        for (var [key, value] of data.entries()) { 
              console.log(key, value);
          }
```

Comment: Did this still its showing null on console

Comment: And the form data is also going in the url.